# D3 transition line happening twice

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am very new to D3, I am trying to make a simple live chart loosely based on a snippet from here: https://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/

I want to be able to add a number of lines to a moving live chart and have them be updated from a web socket (I know how to do that bit!!)

When I try and add a second line the chart doesn't update smoothly, I think the transition is being called twice. Any help gratefully received.

Code below but here's a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/q8qgbj58/

```
var n = 243;
var random = d3.randomNormal(0, .2);

var duration = 500;
var now = new Date(Date.now() - duration);

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 40},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var x = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain([now - (n - 2) * duration, now - duration])
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([-1, 1])
    .range([height, 0]);

var lineNames = [];
var lines = {};
var data = {};

var line = d3.line()
    .curve(d3.curveBasis)
    .x(function(d, i) { return x(now - (n - 1 - i) * duration); })
    .y(function(d, i) { return y(d); });

g.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var axis = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + y(0) + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

createLine("one");
createLine("two");

d3.selectAll(".line")
    .transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .ease(d3.easeLinear)
        .on("start", tick);

function createLine(name) {
    lineNames.push(name);

    data[name] = d3.range(n).map(random);

    lines[name] = d3.line()
        .curve(d3.curveBasis)
        .x(function(d, i) { return x(now - (n - 1 - i) * duration); })
        .y(function(d, i) { return y(d); });

    g.append("g")
      .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
        .append("path")
        .datum(data[name])
        .attr("class", "line");
}

function tick() {
    var index;
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < lineNames.length; ++i) {
        index = lineNames[i];

        // Push a new data point onto the back.
        data[index].push(random());

        // Redraw the line.
        d3.select(this)
          .attr("d", lines[index])
          .attr("transform", null);

        // Pop the old data point off the front.
        data[index].shift();
    }

    now = new Date();
    x.domain([now - (n - 2) * duration, now - duration]);
    axis.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .ease(d3.easeLinear)
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x));


    // Slide it to the left.
    d3.active(this)
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(now - (n - 1) * duration) + ")")
    .transition()
      .on("start", tick);
}
```

Comment: My initial inclination is the tick function is being called twice as often as it should. I could be wrong, but it looks like the function is called once by each line, but each call impacts both lines. I would have expected each line to call tick and impact only that line. Or tick to be called once and impact both lines.

Comment: I have added a fiddle to show the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the issue was with updating the data for all the lines when one line was calling "tick". You will notice your example works fine with 1 line and is even more jerky with 3 lines. This is because of the for loop in the function tick. The data binding in D3 is very useful, but takes some time to get used to using. 
The two major code changes I made were to make the line() a variable and removed the for loop from the tick function. An updated fiddle (I tried to just comment out the original code, so you can easily see the difference): https://jsfiddle.net/s07d2hs3/

```
var line = d3.line()
   .curve(d3.curveBasis)
   .x(function(d, i) { return x(now - (n - 1 - i) * duration); })
   .y(function(d, i) { return y(d); });

function tick() {
    var index;
    var i;
   // Push a new data point onto the back.
   this.__data__.push(random());
   // Redraw the line.
   d3.select(this)
      .attr("d", line)
      .attr("transform", null);

   // Pop the old data point off the front.
      this.__data__.shift();

    now = new Date();
    x.domain([now - (n - 2) * duration, now - duration]);
    axis.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .ease(d3.easeLinear)
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

    // Slide it to the left.
    d3.active(this)
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(now - (n - 1) * duration) + ")")
    .transition()
      .on("start", tick);
}
```

Cleaned up fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lr5dxgr0/2/

Comment: Ok, I think I have a glimmer of understanding. I think I confused the "line" function with the path that represents the line on the screen. Your fiddle is a bit confusing but I got my head  round it. I have tidied mine up a bit here: https://jsfiddle.net/s07d2hs3/

Comment: Sorry, for the messy fiddle. I was trying to balance giving the answer and showing the answer. Its **very** helpful to set a break point in dev tools inside the tick function, then look at what 'this' contains. The framework will keep track of a lot of things for you. I cleaned up the fiddle and added to original post.